# How to send text to an input element with multiple instances of the classname

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

Using selenium vba I am trying to get the 3rd instance of the classname of searchInput and sendkeys to it. I was able to get it with using xpath,

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[9]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input").SendKeys ("test ")
```

The problem with that is the body div is sometimes 9 and other times 11 and other times 7 and so on.

I have tried:

```
set parentSearch = bot.findElementByCSS(".searchInput")
parentSearch(3).sendKeys("test")

bot.findElementByCSS(".searchInput")(3).sendkeys("test")
```

and various others

```
<div class="cdk-live-announcer-element cdk-visually-hidden" aria-atomic="true" aria-live="polite"></div>
> <div id="cdk-describedby-message-container" class="cdk-visually-hidden" style="visibility: hidden;">.</div>
<div class="cdk-overlay-container"></div>
> <div class="tutorial-popup-container">...</div>
<div id="svgProviderContainer" style="display: none;"></div>
<div style="left: -1000px; overflow: scroll; position: absolute; top: -1000px; border: none; box-sizing: content-box; height: 200px; margin: Opx; padding: Opx; width:
200px;">...</div>
><div class="slicer-dropdown-popup visual" focus-nav-mode="Group" style="background-color: rgb(26, 26, 26);">...</div>
<div class="slicer-dropdown-popup visual" focus-nav-mode="Group" style="background-color: rgb(26, 26, 26); width: 101.625px; transform: scale(0.572222); left: 378.722
px; top: 120.944px; transform-origin: left top; display: none;"> == $0
<div class="slicer-dropdown-content"> flex
<div class="slicerContainer isMultiSelectEnabled"> flex

(not in html-the below block)
<div class="searchHeader show" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-color: rgb(200, 200, 200); background: rgb(26, 26, 26);"> flex
<span class="powervisuals-glyph search icon searchIcon" title="Search" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"X</span>
<input type="text" aria-label="Search" placeholder="Search" spellcheck="false" class="search Input" drag-resize-disabled="true" style="background: rgb(26, 26,
26); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10.6667px; font-family: Tahoma;" pbi-focus-tracker-idx="9">
</div>
```

HTML Snapshot:

[image: html]

Comment: Did you add some extra **`>`** characters intentionally/manually within the HTML?

Comment: i added in the ► to point to it. I changed it to make it more clear.

Comment: The class is not as you show it in your code v html v image. It should be `FindElementByCss(".searchInput")`

Comment: scratch that, I see what you mean. I corrected it in the question. I got it transposed when I wrote the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* to the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *FindElementByCss*:

  ```
  bot.FindElementsByCss("input.searchInput[aria-label='Search'][placeholder='Search']")([3]).sendkeys("test")
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath*:

  ```
  bot.FindElementsByXPath("//input[@class='searchInput' and @aria-label='Search'][@placeholder='Search']")([3]).sendkeys("test")
  ```

Comment: Thank you. That does work, but it works for the 1st instance. It is used 14 times on the page and I am wanting to target the 3rd. @DebanjanB

Comment: would I say bot.FindElementByCss("input.searchInput[aria-label='Search'][placeholder='Search']")(3).sendkeys("test")? What is the correct way of saying the 3rd instance?

Comment: @Red Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: it says error Expected end of Statement. So I tried ```bot.FindElementsByXPath("//input[@class='searchInput' and @aria-label='Search'][@placeholder='Search']")([3]).SendKeys ("test")``` and it worked!!! will you update that syntax so I can mark answer correct. Thank you for your help!@DebanjanB